# iPhone: making web calls to example.com API

Tags: ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to verify that from my iPhone App, I can call my custom website API (PHP) and send/receive information without any issues. If so, if there a preferred transaction language? XML, JSON, something else?

I'm just not sure if any web calls need to be made through SSL only or not... just a harmless question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either XML or JSON. JSON is considered more light weight than XML though.

Comment: Thanks, Hetal. So there's no reason to think that I can't make normal web calls like I would any other web application?

Answer (score 0):

I think json should be a good medium for parsing. json-framework makes it easy to turn NSDictionary and primitive objects into json data and vice versa.

Makes web services using json a breeze.

```
{ name : value , name : value } = NSDictionary
[ value , value , value] = NSArray
NSString, NSNumber, BOOL and NSNull are the items it create, I believe.
```

check out this page https://github.com/stig/json-framework

I will include some code I used that is built against the json-framework and works with json web services.

```
- (NSDictionary*) sendJSONRPCRequestTo:(NSString*) url 
                            forCommand:(NSString*)command 
                        withParamaters:(NSMutableArray*) parameters 
                           synchronous:(BOOL) sendSynchronous
{

    if (self.commandId == nil)
    {
        self.commandId = @"1";//Just set a commandID
    }

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.baseTransaction makeNewRequestFor:url];

    NSMutableDictionary *mainPackage = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [mainPackage setValue:self.commandId forKey:@"id"];
    [mainPackage setValue:command forKey:@"method"];
    [mainPackage setValue:parameters forKey:@"params"];

    NSString *jsonData = [mainPackage JSONRepresentation];

    [request setValue:command forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-JSON-RPC"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    if (jsonData != nil && [jsonData isEqual:@""] == NO)
    {
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:[jsonData length]] stringValue] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    }

    [request setHTTPBody:[jsonData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    if (sendSynchronous)
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse   * response = nil;
        NSError             * error = nil;

        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]; 

        NSString *jsonResult = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

        NSDictionary *jsonDict = nil;

        @try 
        {
            jsonDict = [jsonResult JSONValue];
        }
        @catch (NSException * e) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",jsonResult);
            jsonDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                [jsonDict setValue:self.commandId forKey:@"id"];
                [jsonDict setValue:@"Unable to call function on server" forKey:@"error"];
                [jsonDict setValue:[NSNull null] forKey:@"result"];
        }
        @finally
        {
            return jsonDict;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

This code is used against jayrock webservices on a .net server.

Comment: Sending JSON as well? Or just using POST variables?

Comment: well that framework does not actually send the webservice requests.. Ill ammend my answer to include some code as an example

Answer (score 0):

The SDK lacks much native support for XML and JSON.  Third party library support is a bit better for JSON - I'd use that.

You don't need to use SSL - you can use whatever protocol and port you want.

You could do something like `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];`, with `NSMutableURLRequest`, `NSURLResponse`, and `NSError` as the three parameters.

Comment: SDK offers native XML support with NSXMLParser. But you're right that JSON requires 3rd party libraries. [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) is considered to be the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

You can make calls to any URL using an HTTP library or built in Cocoa Framework code.

I recommend [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which allows for asynchronous HTTP requests and easy progress reporting.

You can parse returned data (as XML) with the [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html) class. The downside to this class is that it's linear and not so flexible. Ray Wenderlich has [an article on the topic of XML parsing on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562478/native-json-support-in-ios) which mentions a [JSON parser for iOS](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/).

Comment: I would ASIHTTPRequest in conjunction with https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD because you can do show the loading screen and then run a synchronous web api request in another thread. MBProgressHUD makes it very easy to do this. Also use JSON and JSON-framework as mentioned below. JSON will unbelievably easier than XML on iOS.