# How do I populate a NSArray from a mysql database in Objective-C?

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

I'd like to populate an NSArray for a Picker from my database. I'm using this code at the moment:

```
NSArray *arrayToLoadPicker = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Data1", @"Data2", @"Data3", nil];
```

I wrote a PHP script on my server and this code returns an array (this seemed the most logical way to deal with it, to me). How can I populate said NSArray with the elements given by the script? I use a MySQL database.

Thank you guys

Comment: How do you access you php script? What exactly does your php script output?

Comment: Simplest thing to do is to use an NSMutableArray and write a loop to read from your MySQL output and insert into the array.

Comment: @eelco I create a NSURL with the URL of my script but then I don't know how to deal with it.<br />My PHP script is the following: *$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table"); while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { echo $row['field']; }*

Answer (score 1):

If your server is a web (http) server and your client is an iOS application, I'd recommend that your server returns the array in JSON format, and your client parses it with some JSON framework.
[Native JSON support in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562478/native-json-support-in-ios)