# Getting a list of Images from a website and displaying it

Tags: ios, xcode

I am creating an iOS application that is suppose to get the list of images present on the website and display them as tiles on the screen(similar to the displaying of images from photo library). I can display a single image from a URL in UIImageView but when it comes to displaying the complete list of images from a website, i am clueless. Any help in the right direction or any useful tutorial will be appreciated.

Comment: Dose the images have ID´s ? (Use firebug or Opera Dragonfly to check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this question. I'll give you a quick response to each one.

1: download a list of images

This could be as straight forward as using +arrayWithContentsOfURL: if you have complete control over your website. Be sure to dispatch the downloading to avoid blocking the UI thread.

```
NSURL *URL = self.URLOfImages;
dispatch_queue_t dispatch = dispatch_queue_create("fetch.images", NULL);
dispatch_async(dispatch, ^{
    NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.images = images;
    });
});
dispatch_release(dispatch);
```

NOTE: The URL must return the exact format expected by NSArray and self.images must notify the view that it needs to reload itself ie. `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

If you have less control over the URL, you will need to create a request using something like NSURLRequest, fetch the data using something like NSURLConnection, and parse out the the list of images from the response to create the array of images.

In a much more complex scenario, paging will be involved. This will require only downloading some of the list, then as more images are needed requesting more images then.

2: display the list of images

This could be as simple as using a UITableView with UITableViewCells that use the UITableViewCellStyleDefault style, then set the imageView property in each cell.

To get a better view of the image you could write use a custom table view cell subclassed from UITableViewCell. This would allow you to use a custom placement of the image and set the size of the image to what ever you would like.

In a much more complex senario, you could create your own custom view that contains a UIScrollView that you would place all the images in.

Comment: Thanks Jeffery, One thing i don't understand. What do you mean by complete control over the website?

Comment: Can you create new URLs on the server and can you control the content type, the data, and the formatting returned from those URLs. For +arrayWithContentsOfURL: to work, you will need the URL to return a properly formatted plist (see: [Understanding XML Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/UnderstandXMLPlist/UnderstandXMLPlist.html)). The plist returned cannot be wrapped, encoded, or escaped in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a web service that scrapes this "list" (assuming you don't actually have internal access to the server). I would suggest using libcurl and PHP in order to attain the list.

http://www.sitepoint.com/own-web-service-php-xml-rpc/

Then spit out the list in JSON format and parse it using a library available to iOS:

[Native JSON support in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562478/native-json-support-in-ios)

(may need to see what recent advancements have been made regarding JSON parsing, I seem to remember something about this particular topic has experienced change in recent history).

Official doc on libcurl and PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

**(TAKEN FROM THE ABOVE STACKOVERFLOW QUESTION):**

> Updated answer for iOS 5:
>
> JSON support is now native to iOS with NSJSONSerialization, but in
>   terms of performance, it pales in comparison to JSONKit.
>
> I suggest that you use JSONKit as opposed to NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: Also note that if you are doing this on the device, you'll have to put the website in a whitelist, otherwise iOS will not access it.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed its not working on the device. I have tried searching on the internet but i cant find any reference to how i can add the URl in the white list. Can you kindly guide me or point me to some tutorial or something?

Answer (score 0):

in google chrome browser:

1. navigate to page you want to see all images
2. press f12
3. select "Network" tab
4. scroll through all the request images, these are in order the page was rendered.

Also:

1. Select "Application" tab
2. under images, browse the list of images