# How to get url image from content a url in iOS. help me?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, nsurl

I have a problem with how to get an image from a URL.

I have tried:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringwithFormat:@"http://kenh14.vn/c102/20120715022212850/ngoc-trinh-la-model-thi-khong-nen-ngai-the-hien.chn"]];
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
[connection start];

NSData *data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchrounousRequest:request returningResoibse:nil error:nil];
```

I would like to use this image in a `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 5):

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

The sample code [LazyTableImages.app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394) from apple may be what you want. Good luck.

Comment: thanks.i want to download a list of images from a website and display it.plase help me.

Comment: @user1528296 plz check the update. the sample code will be helpful.

Comment: @user1528296 If this is what you want, you can accept this answer:)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are asking how to make an `UIImageView` simply display what ever image is found on a website. (Your listed URL above is not to an image, it is to a web site)

This is very impractical but I suppose is still possible. I personally don't know how to do this, but this link may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10387801/716216

However, if you wish to simply display an image from its own URL, this can be done quite easily.

e.x: http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png

If you are creating the `UIImageView` completely programmatically:

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"]]]];
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
```

If your image view is instantiated elsewhere, and you just want to apply the image to it:

```
[myImageView setImage: [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"]]]];
```

Comment: thanks.i want to download a list of images from a website and display it.plase help me.