# How to convert an JSON array to array in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, arrays, json

How can i convert this JSON array:

This is a serialized JSON array

```
    2012-06-18 09:22:07.647 TableView[468:f803] (
                {
                "Countries" = Iceland;
                 "id"=9046567;
                  "name"=abceeeffdsg;


            },
                {
                "Countries" = Greenland;
                "id"=3524695;
                "name"=gsfjgfsethju;
    },
                {
                 "Countries" = Switzerland;
                 "id"=4613583;
                 "name"=hdfkdgs;
        )
```

But I need to convert this arrays into following arrays:

```
     {
                   NSArray* Countries =         (
                        Iceland,
                        Greenland,
                        Switzerland,
                    );
NSArray *id=(9046567,3524695,4613583 );
NSArray * name=(abceeeffdsg,gsfjgfsethju,hdfkdgs);
                }
```

Or else i just wanted to display these items on my table view as a cell..
anyone can suggest some codes and explain this....

Comment: You forgot to post the JSON array...

Comment: This is not a valid JSON, let alone not array ;) See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562478/native-json-support-in-ios) thread for JSON serialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fetch all countries into an array:

```
NSArray *countries = [myArrayFromJson valueForKey:@"Countries"];
```

Note that the second snippet of yours is an `NSDictionary` with one key ('Countries') and an array of values. So it's not just 'an array'...

So, if you would really like to have it like this you could do:

```
// After collecting the values into 'countries' array like above...
NSDictionary *countriesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:countries forKey:@"Countries"];
```

Comment: If i convert it to array and NSLog countries array i got this 2012-06-18 10:06:27.246 TableView[841:f803] (null)

Comment: I have just tested it and works fine... Can you post a snippet of the actual code? (How you get your first array and trying to pluck the countries)

Comment: It works fine. I did just a mistake. I converted to array before serialization. Now it works. Thanks a lot!