# How to create objects from JSON NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, cocoa, object, nsdictionary

I have a `PHP` Webservice that returns a `JSON` string with this format:

```
[{"latitud":"37.995914","longitud":"-1.139705","nombre":"Miguel de 
Unamuno"},{"latitud":"37.995433","longitud":"-1.140143","nombre":"Calle
 Pina"},{"latitud":"37.99499","longitud":"-1.140361","nombre":"Calle 
Moncayo"},{"latitud":"37.993918","longitud":"-1.139392","nombre":"Calle 
Moncayo2"},{"latitud":"37.994588","longitud":"-1.138543","nombre":"Calle 
Salvador de Madriaga"}]
```

In my project, I have a custom class with the next structure:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface PCoordenada : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D *punto;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *nombre;
@end
```

Then, I´m using other class for the main app:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PCoordenada.h"

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSData * HTTPResponse;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary * dic;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *arrayCoord;
@property (nonatomic,strong) PCoordenada *coor;

-(IBAction)GetDataFrom:(id)sender;

@end
```

I wonder how I can make a array of PCoordenada's objects that contain the info of JSON string.

Anyone could help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Native JSON support in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562478/native-json-support-in-ios)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:YOUR_URL]];
NSArray *arrRequests = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

which will put the JSON into an NSArray of objects.  Each of these objects is an NSDictionary.  So then you just need to loop through the NSArray to get out the NSDictionary of each.

```
//now let's loop through the array and generate the necessary annotation views
for (int i = 0; i<= arrRequests.count - 1; i++) {
    //now let's dig out each and every json object
    NSDictionary *dict = [arrRequests objectAtIndex:i];}
```

Each NSDictionary that you get from the loop holds the JSON properties as a key in the NSDictionary:

```
 NSString *address = [NSString stringWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"Address"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also a good practice to use multithreading when reading JSON for better performance.
[This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) article has a very simple to follow how-to. I recommend a read.