# How to parse an array?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I am getting a response like this from a webservice. Can anybody tell me how to parse this to make it as individual strings`"Info":`

```
{
  "name":"gdgdgdgd",
  "desc":"Cosmopolitan life, adventurous outlook, 'been there done that' attitude, and yet the way the life ...",
  "address1":" 2nd A Main ",
  "address2":" Layout,"
},
```

Comment: Use NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score 2):

That's a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) representation of an object.

In iOS 5, JSON classes we're added as [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Here's a tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Here's another thread discussing other options as well like JSONKit, YAJL

[Native JSON support in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562478/native-json-support-in-ios)

Answer (score -1):

do like this using json library

NSMutableDictionary *listd=[dict objectForKey:@"merchantInfo"];

```
if([listd isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])

{

   stringshopname=[listd objectForKey:@"name"]; 
   stringshopdesc=[listd objectForKey:@"desc"];


}
```