# how to decode json message

Tags: php, ios, json

I have the following json encoded function to display push notification for iphone.....
but what i need is to store just push notification message in DB...
So that i can show that message in website which is developed by using php....
so i need to decode this json format

```
private function _jsonEncode($array = false)
{
    //Using json_encode if exists
    if (function_exists('json_encode')) {
        return json_encode($array);
    }
    if (is_null($array))
        return 'null';
    if ($array === false)
        return 'false';
    if ($array === true)
        return 'true';
    if (is_scalar($array)) {
        if (is_float($array)) {
            return floatval(str_replace(",", ".", strval($array)));
        }
        if (is_string($array)) {
            static $jsonReplaces = array(array("\\", "/", "\n", "\t", "\r", "\b", "\f", '"'), array('\\\\', '\\/', '\\n', '\\t', '\\r', '\\b', '\\f', '\"'));
            return '"' . str_replace($jsonReplaces[0], $jsonReplaces[1], $array) . '"';
        } else
            return $array;
    }
    $isList = true;
    for ($i = 0, reset($array); $i < count($array); $i++, next($array)) {
        if (key($array) !== $i) {
            $isList = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    $result = array();
    if ($isList) {
        foreach ($array as $v)
            $result[] = $this->_jsonEncode($v);
        return '[' . join(',', $result) . ']';
    } else {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v)
            $result[] = $this->_jsonEncode($k) . ':' . $this->_jsonEncode($v);
        return '{' . join(',', $result) . '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Indent indent indent!

Comment: This is a statement of needs not a question. What is your problem?

Comment: am new to json so i need this json message to decode

Comment: why are you using a custom function to encode, use `json_encode` and `json_decode`

Comment: There is no code there that has anything to do with a notification message.

Comment: am getting this warning...Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/content/69/11486669/html/timesheet-manager/class_APNS.php on line 719

Comment: You dont json_decode an array as an array is not json

Comment: read @user2041318 answer and follow the links

Comment: k i got what you said so what should i do now to decode

Comment: the message is encoded in this format:{"aps":{"alert":"mounika4"},"acme2":["bang","whiz"]}...so how can i decode the message which is in this format

Comment: With `json_decode()`, if you are asking for PHP decode. If you need to know for iOS decode, then follow this link > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562478/native-json-support-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would use standard PHP functions:

json_encode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

json_decode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted... What's wrong with PHP built in functions and why can't OP just use them?

Comment: the message is encoded in this format:{"aps":{"alert":"mounika4"},"acme2":["bang","whiz"]}...so how can i decode the message which is in this format

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the json_decode() function of php to decode the json data. There is no need to write the code for decoding the json, if php is providing the in-built function for the same.

Comment: when i use it it is giving warning.warning...Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/content/69/11486669/html/timesheet-manager/class_APNS.php on line 719

Answer (score 0):

This is because your json string is not correct.
you should use '{' after the '[' and you should define the indexes in big bracket string.

for example

json_decode('{"aps":{"alert":"mounika4"},"acme2":[{"0":"bang","1":"whiz"}]}');

or

json_decode('{"aps":{"alert":"mounika4"},"acme2":{"0":"bang","1":"whiz"}}');

whatever array format you want.